# Filter and group properties from JArray

Tags: arrays, json, json.net

I receive an array from an API like so:

```
[
    {
        "uniqueId": "Env30362",
        "field": "StartDate",
        "value": "1999-01-01",
        "modificationDateTime": "2020-12-12T04:10:55.0970000Z",
        "modificationState": "Created"
    },
    {
        "uniqueId": "Env30362",
        "field": "EndDate",
        "value": "2020-01-01",
        "modificationDateTime": "2020-12-12T04:10:55.0970000Z",
        "modificationState": "Created"
    },
    {
        "uniqueId": "Env30363",
        "field": "AnnualIncentiveCurrency",
        "value": "EUR",
        "modificationDateTime": "2020-12-06T04:10:52.0970000Z",
        "modificationState": "Created"
    },
    {
        "uniqueId": "Env30363",
        "field": "NatureOfContract",
        "value": "Permanent",
        "modificationDateTime": "2020-12-06T04:10:52.0970000Z",
        "modificationState": "Created"
    },
    {
        "uniqueId": "Env30363",
        "field": "FinalProcessDate",
        "value": "2020-12-01",
        "modificationDateTime": "2020-12-06T04:10:52.0970000Z",
        "modificationState": "Created"
    },
    {
        "uniqueId": "Env30362",
        "field": "Currency",
        "value": "EUR",
        "modificationDateTime": "2020-12-13T04:10:55.0970000Z",
        "modificationState": "Changed"
    },
    {
        "uniqueId": "Env30362",
        "field": "Status",
        "value": "Active",
        "modificationDateTime": "2020-12-13T04:10:55.0970000Z",
        "modificationState": "Changed"
    },
    {
        "uniqueId": "Env30363",
        "field": "DateOfBirth",
        "value": "1980-12-01",
        "modificationDateTime": "2020-12-10T04:10:52.0970000Z",
        "modificationState": "Changed"
    },
        {
        "uniqueId": "Env30363",
        "field": "HiringReason",
        "value": "Growth",
        "modificationDateTime": "2020-12-10T04:10:52.0970000Z",
        "modificationState": "Changed"
    }
]
```

I would like to filter and group the fields based on the `uniqueId` and `modificationState` so that I can create a new `JObject` with all fields and values associated to creation / change.  I've tried different approaches with Linq, but I have not found a way to use multiple `where` clauses on an `IEnumerable` of `JToken`

Desired output:

```
{
"uniqueId": "Env30363",
"modificationState": "Created"
"finalProcessDate": "2020-12-01",
"modificationDateTime": "2020-12-06T04:10:52.0970000Z",
"natureOfContract": "Permanent",
"annualIncentiveCurrency" : "EUR"
}

{
"uniqueId": "Env30363",
"modificationState": "Changed"
"modificationDateTime": "2020-12-10T04:10:52.0970000Z",
"hiringReason": "growth",
"dateOfBirth" : "1980-12-01"
}

{
"uniqueId": "Env30362",
"modificationState": "Created",
"modificationDateTime": "2020-12-12T04:10:55.0970000Z",
"endDate": "2020-01-01",
"startDate" : "1999-01-01"
}

{
"uniqueId": "Env30362",
"modificationState": "Changed",
"modificationDateTime": "2020-12-13T04:10:55.0970000Z",
"currency" : "EUR",
"status": "Active"
}
```

How can I achieve this with NewtonSoft.Json?

Comment: *I’ve tried different approaches with Linq but I have not found a way to use multiple where clauses on an IEnumerable of JToken* - then can you please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] showing what did not work?  It's not clear how the input is supposed to get transformed to the output, especially since the output, lacking outer `[` and `]` brackets, isn't even well-formed JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information in your question it looks like you want something like this (I'm assuming C# as your question did not specify a language):

```
JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);

var camel = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy();

JArray transformedArray = new JArray(
    array.Children<JObject>()
         .GroupBy(jo => new 
         { 
             UniqueId = (string)jo["uniqueId"], 
             ModificationState = (string)jo["modificationState"],
             ModificationDateTime = (DateTime)jo["modificationDateTime"]
         })
         .OrderBy(g => g.Key.ModificationDateTime)
         .ThenByDescending(g => g.Key.ModificationState)  // if same time, put Created before Changed
         .ThenBy(g => g.Key.UniqueId)
         .Select(g => new JObject(
             new JProperty("uniqueId", g.Key.UniqueId),
             new JProperty("modificationState", g.Key.ModificationState),
             new JProperty("modificationDateTime", g.Key.ModificationDateTime),
             g.Select(jo => new JProperty(camel.GetPropertyName((string)jo["field"], false), jo["value"]))
         ))
);
```

This will give you a new `JArray` of `JObjects` with the new format.

Here is a working demo:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/cT7F33